# Pages with a loop (index, archive) are loading the first image as post_thumbnail

Tags: loop, post-thumbnails, header-image

Using post thumbnails for custom header images -- works fine on straight pages.  But custom templates that load a loop (including index) are pulling the first image instead of using the one set in the featured image field.

Anyone seen this before?

Thanks!

-m

Comment: what theme are you using? can you post the code of the custom template(s)?

Comment: It's a custom theme.  I'm using     <?php the_post_thumbnail('header'); ?> to get the image and then there's a loop that looks, pretty much like any other -- `<?php

   $args = array('post_type' => 'people', 'category_name'=> 'current');
   $people_posts = new WP_Query($args);

   if($people_posts->have_posts()) : 
      while($people_posts->have_posts()) : 
         $people_posts->the_post();
?>`
   etc etc....

Answer (score 0):

Your theme uses a custom function to get the first image, if you post your index.php codes here you maybe find someone to help.

Comment: Nope -- just the standard '<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>`